# Cannot add answer, I have 108 points (100 from association)

Tags: support, answers, community

The title tells it (almost) all.

I mean to write an answer to

[How do I separate disc brake pads after accidentally pulling the front brake while the wheel is off?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-do-i-separate-disc-brake-pads-after-accidentally-pulling-the-front-brake-whi)

but I get the sign

"protected by Community♦ Sep 21 '12 at 5:39

Thank you for your interest in this question. Because it has attracted low-quality or spam answers that had to be removed, posting an answer now requires 10 reputation on this site. "

According to the sign, I should be able to post an answer. What is the issue?

Comment: I think this is a bug with the whole SE system, so this should go to meta.SE or something. It's not bicycle specific afaik.

Comment: Try answering a couple more normal questions, get up over 110 and see if it then permits you to answer the original question.   Could be the 100 association points are being treated differently in error.

Comment: @Criggie - I thought about it. But I think someone from SE or very acquainted with this topic may give the right answer. Perhaps Batman is right.

Comment: @Criggie - Could you upvote one of my two questions so I get to 113, just to test this? You can remove the upvote later on.

Comment: @sancho.s Try now.

Comment: @zenbike - As commented below, having 113 points removed the restriction. But such restriction contradicts the stated spirit of the 100 bonus points, as Evert pointed out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I read "**10 reputation on this site**" to mean on Bicycles, rather than on SE in general. So Criggie's comment is correct - try getting up over 110 and that should fix the issue.

I'm not convinced that this is a bug in the code per se, it's more a bug in the wording. They could say "requires you to have earned 10 reputation".

Comment: Maybe. Could you upvote one of my two questions so I get to 113, just to test this? You can remove the upvote later on.

Comment: @sancho.s done. See what happens and let us know

Comment: That is it. Now I can post answers.

Comment: That's sorta disingenous. but indeed its on [this site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270838/10-reputation-requirement-to-answer-a-question-but-i-have-101).

Comment: Here's from the reputation faq though, which contradicts this: "If you are an experienced Stack Exchange network user with 200 or more reputation on at least one site, you will receive a starting +100 reputation bonus to get you past basic new user restrictions. " I interpret that explicitly as +100 rep on *this site* (#), for exactly the reason the OP has stated. (# since the 200 or more rep is related to other sites.)